# Push failed Heroku: Can't resolve './views/Home' in '/frontend/src'

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, mern

I'm trying to push a MERN stack app to Heroku for the first time. Express serves the React app successfully when I run the production build on my local machine. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Per the Heroku Node.js troubleshooter I...

Specified node and npm versions in package.json

```
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x",
    "npm": "8.x"
  },
```

Specified the buildpack.

```
$ heroku buildpacks
=== my-app Buildpack URL
heroku/nodejs
```

The relevant portion of the logs appears to be:

```
 Creating an optimized production build...
   Failed to compile.
   
   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './views/Home' in '/tmp/build_b656807b/frontend/src'
   
   
 -----> Build failed
   
   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
   
   If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
   https://help.heroku.com/
   
   Love,
   Heroku
   
  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
  !     Push failed
```

Here are the scripts in package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "client": "npm start --prefix frontend",
    "start": "node backend/server",
    "server": "nodemon backend/server",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build --prefix frontend"
  }
```

Comment: can you see if it is not an issue with the small and big case of words + can you share the build script also

Comment: What should I look for specifically related to case sensitivity? Also, I edited the post to include the scripts.

Comment: Just as a test, I renamed `views/Home` to `views/home`. Git did not detect that as a version change worth committing. What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was resolved by...

1. Deleting the `Home` component and re-creating it with a different name.
2. Removing the `PORT` variable from `.env`.
3. Setting the Express listener to look for the Heroku port by default, and to failover to the dev port.

   const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6060